# How to update field for EmbeddedDocument in graphene mongo python

Tags: python, mongodb, graphene-python

I'm trying to update one field of IgThread EmbeddedDocument, and error occurs:
`'IgThread' object has no attribute 'save'`

I've tried some weird solutions, non of them work.
There is bug in current code

Mutation:

```
def mutate(self, _, **kwargs):
    ig_pk = kwargs['ig_pk']
    thread_input = kwargs['ig_thread']

    lead_ = Lead.objects(ig__pk=ig_pk).first()

    for thread in lead_.messages.ig:

        Lead.objects(
            ig__pk=ig_pk,
            messages__ig__thread_id=thread_input.thread_id,
        ).update(
            push_all__messages__ig__S__messages=new_messages,
        )

        thread.last_activity_at = thread_input.last_activity_at
        thread.save()
```

Parent:

```
class Lead(Document):
    id = fields.ObjectIdField()
    messages = fields.EmbeddedDocumentField(Messages)
```

Nested EmbeddedDocument:

```
class Messages(EmbeddedDocument):
    ig = fields.EmbeddedDocumentListField(IgThread)
```

Deeper:

```
class IgThread(EmbeddedDocument):
    thread_id = fields.StringField()
    last_activity_at = fields.StringField()
```

I want to update last_activity_at
Pls, help, I have to fix that bug and no one cant help mi with this in the office :<

Answer (score 0):

Solved! It was easy...

```
def mutate(self, _, **kwargs):
    ig_pk = kwargs['ig_pk']
    thread_input = kwargs['ig_thread']

    lead_ = Lead.objects(ig__pk=ig_pk).first()

    for thread in lead_.messages.ig:

        Lead.objects(
            ig__pk=ig_pk,
            messages__ig__thread_id=thread_input.thread_id,
        ).update(
            push_all__messages__ig__S__messages=new_messages,
        )

        lead_ = Lead.objects(ig__pk=ig_pk).first() <--------
        thread.last_activity_at = thread_input.last_activity_at
        lead_.save() <--------
```